# Include missing dates with missing values with libreoffice-calc

Tags: missing-data, libreoffice-calc

I searched a lot, but didn't find an answer to the following question:

Financial data often come as daily data but with missing dates (weekends, banking holidays ...). I would like to have those data really on a daily basis with missing values, where originally the dates were missing.

So far I did this in liberoffice-calc half-manually, which takes a lot of time. I didn't find ways to really automate this, as there is no fixed rule, which dates are missing.

Example:

I have:

```
21/12/18 1
27/12/18 2
28/12/18 3
02/01/19 4
```

I want:

```
21/12/18 1
22/12/18
23/12/18
24/12/18
25/12/18
26/12/18
27/12/18 2
28/12/18 3
29/12/18
30/12/18
31/12/18
01/01/19
02/01/19 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with liberoffice-calc. In Excel or Google Sheets, I would use a lookup table.

In one tab of the spreadsheet, I was enter the dates I want in column A. In another tab, I would place the actual data I have. Then, in column B of the first tab, I would lookup the value for that day from the data on the second tab.

Comment: This works in libreoffice-calc too, using the functions lookup, vlookup or hlookup. The last ones one needs if one doesn't like lookup's interpolations for missing numbers.

Comment: It did, thanks, but unfortunately I cannot upvote your answer.

Comment: You should be able to accept it since it was your question. But, no sweat either way. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `1` is in B2, put a start date in say D2 and in E2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2,A:A,0)),"")
```

then copy both down to suit.